# How to mock js import in angular 5 in tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to write tests for an angular 5 application which uses a js import, I've been doing research but i cant seen to figure out how to mock the js import. In the test, I just want to check that the bar() method has been called using a spyOn but can't figure out how to do this.

```
import {foo} from 'fooProject';

export class Component {
 constructor(){}

 trigger() {
  foo.bar();
 }
}
```

Comment: Wrap `foo` in an Angular service. Use dependency injection and spy on the injected service.

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can create a factory method for `foo` and then register that factory in the providers for the module. Then, in your unit test, you can inject whatever you want and fake the members.

```
import {foo} from 'fooProject';

export function fooFactory(): any {
    return foo;
}

@NgModule({
    providers: [{ provide: 'Foo', useFactory: fooFactory }]
})
export class YourModule { }
```

```
import { Inject, Component } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent {
 constructor(@Inject('Foo') private foo:any){}

 trigger() {
  this.foo.bar();
 }
}
```

Comment: I've implemented your solution. The following is my test code to inject the mock but it's not working, can you help?

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [],
            declarations: [],
            providers: [
                {provide: 'foo', useClass: FooMock},
            ]
        }).compileComponents();

Comment: @bdeane - Casing is important. `Foo` **or** `foo` but it has to be the same in the test and in the `@Inject` parameter.

Comment: @bdeane - if you need more help please post your spec/test code and what the error is.

Comment: Sorry I posted the incorrect case. The issue seems to be that the injection of the mock class is not working, its still using the import instead of my mocked class

Comment: @bdeane - make sure you prefixed `foo` with `this` so you are calling your injected `foo` instance and not the global one. Remove the `import foo` line from the component and spec.